# SpringBoot application using an external jar with AOP configurations that is added at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, runtime, spring-aop

I've been looking all over the internet without finding a definitive solution to this problem, so, here it goes.

So I have a SpringBoot application that is externally developed. I can not make any modifications over this application, but for my specific solution I need to modify its behaviour on runtime. For that several AOP aspects were developed to intercept the methods that I need of the original SpringBoot Application. Those aspect when tested inside the same application work correctly, but I haven't found any way to make those aspects trigger when included only inside the runtime added jar.

Is this possible? And if so, how?

Comment: If the external application is configured for component scan and your aspects are in the scanner packages, it should just work. Otherwise you will have to configure something by yourself, either Spring-specific or create pure AspectJ aspects and add `-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar` and put your aspects on the classpath. But you cannot expect to do **nothing** and the aspects being picked up magically. Otherwise everyone could hack any Java application. But either way, it should be simple enough.

Comment: @kriegaex I ended up including a class with the Configuration anotation inside the same package and that worked great, thank you for your recommendation. Now the problem is that I would also need to include dependencies to a spring configuration xml inside the web applications context. Would you recommend any way of doing this? Thank you

Comment: I am the AOP guy, not a Spring user. I think there are people more qualified than me to answer that question.